# Schema for inheriting content from central down to subsidiary

Tags: node.js, mongodb, inheritance

We have a content model where we set content at a central level, but users have the ability to edit the content down to subsidiary level if they want to. If they don't want to change anything from what gets set from central they don't have to.

Let's assume a simple api endpoint that just takes in companyId. This is how it would respond:

```
GET /offers (central values)
[{
  offerId: 1,
  title: "Central offer title",
  paragraph: "Lorem ipsum central",
  price: 100
}, {...more offers}]
```

Company 123

```
/offers?companyId=123
[{
  offerId: 1,
  title: "Company offer title",
  paragraph: "Lorem ipsum central", // Inherited from central
  price: 125
}, {...more offers}]
```

Company 456 which is a subsidiary to 123

```
/offers?companyId=456
[{
  offerId: 1,
  title: "Company offer title", // Inherited from Company 1
  paragraph: "Lorem ipsum subsidiary",
  price: 125, // Inherited from Company 1
  custom_field: "A completely custom field for subsidiary" // Field only available for subsidiary
}, {...more offers}]
```

In previous implementations we have done something in the lines of:

```
{
  offerId: 1,
  values: [
    {
      companyId: null,
      title: "Central offer title",
      paragraph: "Lorem ipsum central",
      price: 100
    },
    {
      companyId: 123,
      title: "Company offer title",
      price: 125
    },
    {
      companyId: 456,
      paragraph: "Lorem ipsum subsidiary",
      custom_field: "A completely custom field for subsidiary"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then in the application we have compiled this down so values are specific for subsidiary, but still inheriting data from central or parent company.

Now that we're about to write new applications that should once again allow this type of content inheritance, we're having doubts about this approach and wonder if there's another way to model this.

What other ways exist to model this type of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mongoose? If so - use [Discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html):

```js
const event1 = new Event({ time: Date.now() });
const event2 = new ClickedLinkEvent({ time: Date.now(), url: 'google.com' });
const event3 = new SignedUpEvent({ time: Date.now(), user: 'testuser' });
```

More on that topic in this fine read: https://dev.to/helenasometimes/getting-started-with-mongoose-discriminators-in-expressjs--22m9

---

If not - then I think you should follow the same approach as in mongoose - have each company as a separate document. Because in your old setup, there are a few things:

1. Company resides in Offer document
2. If multiple offers use the same companies, you'd duplicate company data, right?
3. There's no easy way to search for company - you get offers.values and search for a property inside. That's basically traversing your entire database.

If you only search by company (and not offer ID as you said), you can reverse them. But it's still weird. I'd split them in two separate things and use references between them. This way you could:

1. Find company by id
2. Find it's parent (do this until there is no parent; use aggregate to make it in a single query)
3. Get a list of offers for that company (document property) and query them

This approach would allow you to do the opposite (offer to company).

Comment: In the old setup there are thousands of offers, and also hundreds of companies. The company entity is separated from this data, we just use a reference id.
I think that Discriminators solves a different problem than what I'm having. It looks to me that Discriminators just inherits schema, but in my case I want to inherit both schema and its values.

Comment: Clarified post so that it shows that it could be multiple offers